# Koma variable as boolean

Tags: koma-script, conditionals

I would like to have a komavar that is of type `bool` and then depending on whether the option is set or not I would want to import a package. Basically I'm looking for something like

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\newkomavar{abc}
\newkomavar{xyz}
\setkomavar{xyz}{true}

\begin{document}

\usekomavar[\iftrue]{xyz}
   \setkomavar{abc}{yes}
\else
   \setkomavar{abc}{yeah}
\fi
\usekomavar{abc}

\end{document}
```

Similar constructions are possible with `\ifstr`. I was wondering if somebody has an idea or if I should just write my own `.cls` or `.sty` for that. Not sure if it makes sense to have that option in the `.lco`. The goal is to import `\RequirePackage{background}`. (Not for the Draft as a watermark but for some other fancy stuff.)

Comment: Where in the example code do you want to load the packages? Maybe you can put some comments?

Comment: Aren't toggles from `etoolbox` what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\newkomavar{abc}
\newkomavar{xyz}
\setkomavar{xyz}{\iftrue}

\begin{document}

\usekomavar{xyz}
   \setkomavar{abc}{yes}
\else
   \setkomavar{abc}{yeah}
\fi
\usekomavar{abc}

\setkomavar{xyz}{\iffalse}
\usekomavar{xyz}
   \setkomavar{abc}{yes}
\else
   \setkomavar{abc}{yeah}
\fi
\usekomavar{abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this input! I changed it a bit to `\setkomavar{xyz}{true}` and defined `\newcommand{\myif}[1]{\csname if#1\endcsname}` and then used `\usekomavar[\myif]{xyz}` to check the boolean. This way the variable is more accessible for other users.